# How does Angular 2 unload pages?

Tags: angular

We will be creating an Angular 2 application that will have around 200 pages. I know that you can lazy load, eager load, and pre-load.  If a user goes to a page that is lazy loaded and then leaves the page, does it release it from memory?  What about a pre-loaded page?  Does the page stay around since it was pre-loaded?  My concern is that the end user will run out of memory in their browser if they go to too many pages or that the application will take too long for the initial load.

Comment: I agree that unloading is a good question and I hope there will be some good answers about that. But 200 pages ? Do you really need that ? Can't you just reuse components as often as possible and create some pages with those components ? Please add some informations about your 200 pages :)

Comment: Yes.  The 200 pages are really needed.  There will be components shared on all 200 of those pages; but there will be 200 unique pages.  This is for a very large application that will be built over the course of 2 years by multiple teams.

Comment: Very curious about your app :) Will it be open source ? I'd be glad to keep an eye on it. (I shared your issue in Gitter to see if anyone had an idea but no luck apparently).

Comment: This is for an large manufacturing client that will be used internally by the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if by "pages" you mean components, they will be released and GC can clean up ... assuming that you don't do anything that causes it to hold on ... such as subscribing to a long-lived `Observable` (e.g., `router...` or some service you wrote).

Look at the `OnDestroy` lifecycle hook.  Implement `ngOnDestroy()`.  Put a `console.log` in it to confirm that it's called.  THAT is where you can detach handlers.`

But then again you don't lazy load "pages". You lazy load **modules**. These are code. Once code is loaded, there is no way to unload that code without reloading the browser web page AFAIK. That's a browser/JavaScript limitation, not an Angular limitation. Is that your worry?

It is very rare that the application code alone blows the client memory, especially for an app as small as 200 pages.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Yes, I meant modules.  So it looks like Angular 2 becomes similar to ASP.NET MVC in this case but instead of being on the server, it is on the client where it is loading and unloading modules.